# VueJS Component with datalist not showing options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-datalist

I am utilizing VueJS and it's components to build a large series of datalists and selectors.. all with a submit button at the end of it when the form is validated...

so far I can make a datalist inside a component that renders options and has type completion.. works great!  BUT when I attempted to turn the thing into a VueJS Component, and pass in the dataarray as a property... my list of options no longer render

## Two Datalist elements...

[image: two datalist elements]

## Top one is the "raw" datalist, which works 100%

[image]

## But when I goto the vue.js component version, nothing shown as an option...

[image]

## it's just not there, when I mouse over like the first one...

[image]

The datalist VueJS Component

```
<template>
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="item" list="data_input" v-on:input="selectionChanged">
        <datalist id="yourdatalist">
          <option v-for="item in data_input">{{item}}</option>
        </datalist>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Datalist',
  props: ['inputDataList'],
  data () {
    return {
      selection: '',
      item:'',
      data_input:this.inputDataList
    }
  },

methods: {
  selectionChanged: function(element) {
    console.log("selection = "+this.selection+", new value = " + element.target.value);
    var newSelection = element.target.value;

    if (newSelection != this.selection) { 
      // newSelection changes on every keystroke, so you must keep diffing it with your known data
      for (var i=0; i<this.data_input.length; i++) {
        if (this.data_input[i] == newSelection) {
          this.selection = newSelection
          console.log("selection = "+this.selection+" now");
          this.$emit('selectionChanged', this.selection);
        }
      }
    }
  },
},
}
</script>
```

## The calling component HTML code

```
<p>Examples of Datalists</p>
<input type="text" v-model="film" list="films" v-on:input="filmChanged">
    <datalist id="films">
        <option v-for="film in films">{{film}}</option>
    </datalist>
<div v-if="focusedfilm">
  <h6>You have picked {{focusedfilm}}</h6>
</div>
<br/>
<p>Examples of Child Component Datalist</p>
<Datalist :inputDataList="films"/>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't see the `<option>` elements when you inspect the rendered component?

Comment: have you tried to set the attribute 'list' equal to the attribute 'id' of the datalist?

Comment: @AlfredoLanzetta i tried that, but let me try again...

Comment: @FK82 the options are shown in the html, see screenshot... it's just not giving me a dropdown list of the options in Chrome

Comment: Shouldn't you change `<datalist id="yourdatalist">` to `<datalist id="data_input">`?

Comment: @T.Dirks I had tried that before.. but retrying it now... as per earlier suggestions

Comment: @AlfredoLanzetta that was it! it's now rendering.. please can you post that as answer so I can give you pts?

Comment: i post immediatly the answer, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the attribute 'list' equal to the attribute 'id' of the datalist.

Change
`<datalist id="yourdatalist">` to `<datalist id="data_input">`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If [Alfredo Lanzetta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9155633/alfredo-lanzetta) post his answer, you should accept his because he came with it first. I just want to explain why the solution works.

If you have the following code where you want a dropdrown list for an input field

```
<input type="text" v-model="item" list="data_input" v-on:input="selectionChanged">
<datalist id="yourdatalist">
  <option v-for="item in data_input">{{item}}</option>
</datalist>
```

To correctly assign the `datalist` to the input field, the input field needs to have a link to said `datalast`. You can do that with the `list` property of the input field.

The way to link the two, is to set the `list` property of the input field to the id of the `datalist`. As you can see in example from your code, the `datalist` has the id `yourdatalist` but the input field has de `list` property set to `data_input`, thus it is looking for a `datalist` with the id `data_input`. Since there is no `datalist` with said id, you don't get to see that dropdrown list.

Comment: this is great, had no idea about the id needing to match.  Thanks for the in depth exaplainer!